# call different method for two checkbox list

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, onclick

I have two checkbox lists and when any checkbox from any two list is checked i call the method through this event

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
            {
                MainClass.onLayer(val);

                // do the magic here
            } else {
                if (val != undefined) {
                    MainClass.offLayer(val);
                }
    //            alert("false");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is how my checkbox list looks like:

```
    <div class="tabBox_slide">
          <div class="tabcard active">
            <div class="titleList"><span class="list-plus"></span> Census</div>
            <div class="containerGeoFeture">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <label for="IndiaBoundary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="IndiaBoundary"  id="IndiaBoundary"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span> India Boundary </label>
                  <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
                  </li>
                  <li>
                  <label for="IndiaBoundary2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="IndiaBoundary"  id="IndiaBoundary2"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span> India Boundary </label>
                  <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
                  </li>


              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="tabcard">
        <div class="titleList"><span class="list-plus"></span> GPS</div>
        <div class="containerGeoFeture">
          <ul>
            <li class="gpsstyle">

              <label for="gps">
                <input type="checkbox" name="gps"  id="gps"/>
                <span class="checkmark"></span> GPS </label>
              <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

So now the problem is need to call separate methods for the two checkbox lists?How can i do that?

Comment: send your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i add the `id` in div you can set your way !

```
$("#tab1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    });
    $("#tab2 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    });



   <div class="tabBox_slide">
          <div class="tabcard active">
            <div class="titleList"><span class="list-plus"></span> Census</div>
            <div class="containerGeoFeture" id="tab1">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <label for="IndiaBoundary">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="IndiaBoundary"  id="IndiaBoundary"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span> India Boundary </label>
                  <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
                  </li>
                  <li>
                  <label for="IndiaBoundary2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="IndiaBoundary"  id="IndiaBoundary2"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span> India Boundary </label>
                  <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
                  </li>


              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="tabcard">
        <div class="titleList"><span class="list-plus"></span> GPS</div>
        <div class="containerGeoFeture" id="tab2">
          <ul>
            <li class="gpsstyle">

              <label for="gps">
                <input type="checkbox" name="gps"  id="gps"/>
                <span class="checkmark"></span> GPS </label>
              <span class="bgcolor_boundary "></span> 
              </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: total 3 checkbox ?

Comment: No it just a sample there could be more.

Comment: Is there a way through which i could do it without id as it will be very lengthy for me as there are many checkbox in my page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189243/discussion-between-mohammad-malek-and-gaurav).

Answer (score 0):

you can give different name or id to your checkbox like and accordingly call the function

$("input[name='checkbox1']").change(function () {

}

$("input[name='checkbox2']").change(function () {

}

Comment: so i have to include name in every checkbox i create ?

Comment: yes Gaurav, name or id whichever is convenient to differentiate the checkbox. Or else you can write in the checkbox tag itself, like onchange="myFunction()".